# Approximating standard deviation from darts hitting and missing bullseye

Tags: statistics

Aiming for the center, I throw $100$ darts on a dartboard, $25$ of those darts hit within $15$ mm from the center. How do I approximate my own standard deviation using only that information?

Comment: If you agree that the distribution of the darts is normally distributed along the radius and uniformly distributed on the circles concentric with the target...

Comment: I do. How do I do it?

Comment: the mean is zero (mm from the centre of the board) and Normal distribution tables allow you to look up the standard deviation based on 25% of darts being within 15mm.  Then using that standard deviation you can use Normal distribution tables to calculate the remainder of the dataset.

Comment: @Bey’s expanded answer was what I was looking for. If someone has a better question for that answer‭  - feel free to edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per your responses in the comments, you can model this as a truncated multivariate normal distribution.

**Assumptions**: You are always aiming for the bullseye, so our dart throws have a stationary distribution. I mange this is not too controversial but I'm not a darts player, so maybe there are instances where you don't want to hit the bullseye.

Let $\mathbf{r}$ be the 2-d vector that points from the bullseye (assumed to be the origin of our coordinate system) to the location of the dart.

Let $\Sigma$ be the $2 \times 2$ covariance matrix of the darts. This is useful if you want to account for the likely *handedness* of your dart distribution. I bet lefties and righties have different dart distributions when aiming for the bullseye. The general formula for a the $p$-percent confidence region for this model is given by:

$$\mathbf{r}: \mathbf{r}^T\Sigma^{-1}\mathbf{r} \leq  \chi^2_2(p)$$

You can simplify this by making it simply $\Sigma = \sigma^2 \mathbf{I}$ (spherical assumption). We then need to set $\sigma^2$ so that $P(|\mathbf{r}| < 15 mm) = 0.25$. It is found as follows:

$$\mathbf{r}^T(\sigma^2 \mathbf{I})^{-1}\mathbf{r} = \chi^2_2(0.25)$$

Let's simplify the left hand side first:

$$\mathbf{r}^T(\sigma^2 \mathbf{I})^{-1}\mathbf{r} = \frac{1}{\sigma^2}\mathbf{r}^T\mathbf{I}\mathbf{r} = \frac{1}{\sigma^2}\langle\mathbf{r},\mathbf{r}\rangle = \frac{1}{\sigma^2}(x^2+y^2)=\frac{||\mathbf{r}||_2^2}{\sigma^2}$$

Setting this equal to the right hand side (so as to find the boundary of our region), we get:

$$||\mathbf{r}||^2_2 = \sigma^2 \chi^2_2(0.25) \implies ||\mathbf{r}||_2 = \sigma\sqrt{\chi^2_2(0.25)} \approx \sigma \sqrt{0.575} \approx 0.76 \sigma$$

So, we can see that 25% of the probability lies within a circle of radius $0.76\sigma$. Since we know that $||\mathbf{r}||_2 = 15$mm, we can back out that $\sigma = \frac{15}{0.76} = 19.77$mm.

Given this, you generate dart throws using $\mathbf{r} \sim \rm{MVN}(\mathbf{0},19.77^2 \mathbf{I})$ (for example, using R or Python, or an other environment that allows you to draw from an MVN)

This would be a relatively simple model, but it's not completely trivial. You can capture a lot of general featuers of your data.

**Challenge**: Instead of a multivariate normal, use a Gaussian Process -- then things can get very interesting!

Comment: I don't think you need to truncate the MVN... you can eventually miss the target. So also point 2 in your algorithm doesn't apply.

Comment: @N74 I good point. I was assuming no missing the board. Ignoring this makes it simpler.

Comment: @Bey. Thanks for your answer! Is it possible to dumb it down a notch? You see, right now this is the challenge. I’m not a mathematician, this is just a past time. Can you expand on how I get the sigma from my three known values (100, 25 and 15mm). I promise I’ll get to covariance matrixes, multivariate normal distribution and Gaussian processafter that - it sounds interesting! Thanks again!

Comment: @janjarfalk sure thing. I carried out the full calculation for the spherical case. You now just need to learn some programming/statistical language that allows you to draw from a multivariate gaussian.

Comment: @Bey Thanks a lot for a great answer to an apparently bad question!

Comment: @janjarfalk no problem -- got a downvote myself, so apparently someone was none-too-pleased with my answer either. Oh well -- the important thing is you are able to make progress. Good luck as you continue to learn more statistics.